# Adblock убивает все fetch и axios запросы

Tags: javascript, reactjs, requests, axios, fetch

Сделал фронт на React js, бэк на php, все действия вяжутся на fetch запросах и реакции на результат с сервера, на моём [сайте](http://u124078.test-handyhost.ru/) при включенном блокировщике рекламы (тестил только adblock) не работают все запросы на сервер и в каталоге появляется бесконечная загрузка, в личном кабинете ничего не отображается и в консоли только алерты "POST http://g908020p.beget.tech/ net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT", читал подобные посты с проблемами работы сайта при включенном Adblock'е, все говорят, что из тегов надо убирать ключевые слова "adv" или переименовывать файлы, чтобы там тоже не было ничего похожего на рекламу, но у меня и так нет ничего такого, можете проверить на [гите](https://github.com/Artifs/FufukWs), также предоставлю один из десятков запросов, они довольно похожи, все делал по этому паттерну. Если у вас есть предположения, или не готовые решения, я готов попробовать проверить.

```
var form = new FormData()
form.append('JSONPARSE',true);
fetch("http://g908020p.beget.tech",{
    method: 'POST',
    body: form
})
.then(response => response.text())
.then(response => {
    var json = JSON.parse(response)
    setCatalog(json.items)
    setLoading(true)
    console.log(json)

})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Сам не сталкивался, но может проблема в том, что запросы идут на незащмщенное соединение http://... Попробуй тот же функционал, но с сервером на https://

Недавно делал похожий функционал с fetch на тестовый сервер с https, проблем с addblock не было

Comment: Это похоже на правду, я попробовал на локалке загрузить апи базу с https соединением и она не блокируется, в то время, как даже с моего второго локального сервера блокируются данные, сейчас попробую другой хостинг на https.